# Login with firebase + spring on backend

Tags: java, spring, reactjs, firebase, spring-security

This is my first web project so its also my first time doing a login, after a research the best guide I found is for firebase but the problem I have with it is that I need to have Users on my Spring database because I have relationship between entities that involves users
Is still possible to use firebase having users on both sides, firebase and my own server database?

I found another way to do login with spring security but I didnt find good guides to integrate it with react

Comment: You can keep firebase as your authentication method, and use your java spring server to store user data. Login via firebase, then pull user data from server.

Comment: Thanks!  with that aproach, Should I then at every new user, create a new user too on my server database with the same uid as firebase so I can use firebase functions to know what user(of my server database) is logged?

Comment: yes. remember to use the firebase-admin sdk for server side verification of user identity before publishing data to your client.

Comment: thanks! if you want post the answer as a post and I'll accept the answer

Comment: Firebase admin sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup Create a user on firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users Remember to verify client id tokens. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem. I found this [Spring Boot example](https://github.com/savicprvoslav/Spring-Boot-starter) on GithHub. It shows an example of a Firebase-Spring boot integration.